# ¿ Como puedo ocultar una class cuando todas estan nombradas iguales?

Tags: html, css

En mi caso lo que me pasa es que quiero ocultar 3 clases del desplegable del icono de registro en `prestashop`, pero no puedo por que todas las class están nombradas del mismo modo:

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
    <div class="dropdown-item href="..."></div>
</div>
```

Me gustaría quitar la 4ta, la 5ta, y la 6ta.
Me han comentado que desde css hay una orden que puedes ordenar que de una div te oculte con "hidden" o "display: none;" la clases de la posición 4, de la posición 5, y la posición 6.

Por lo tanto me gustaría saber si alguien sabe cul es esta orden para CSS.

Gracias!

Comment: creeria que tenes que usar selectores de hermanos css. ``.dropdown-item:nth-child(4), .dropdown-item:nth-child(5), .dropdown-item:nth-child(6){ display: none; }``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sí, puedes hacerlo con el pseudoselector :nth-child: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

En este caso, para ocultar exactamente el 4º, el 5º y el 6º, lo haríamos así:

```css
.dropdown-item {
  background-color: lime;
  width: 100px;
}

.dropdown-item:nth-child(4), .dropdown-item:nth-child(5), .dropdown-item:nth-child(6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown-item">1</div>
<div class="dropdown-item">2</div>
<div class="dropdown-item">3</div>
<div class="dropdown-item">4</div>
<div class="dropdown-item">5</div>
<div class="dropdown-item">6</div>
<div class="dropdown-item">7</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me ha funcionado a la perfección!